# Blank vertical column/space to the right on ipad mode

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am in the process of creating this website

[image]

if you open developer mode on chrome and change to ipad there is blank column to the extreme right that runs throughout the page. I have no idea whats causing that break and i want to get rid if the space. All I can see is there is a border:box property from reboot.scss. bootsrap 4 is used in this development

any pointers will be much appeciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
html, body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Overlflowing mailto link in footer]

Since you have overflowing/long link to the mail, it is taking up the area. If you use word-break for the same it works, depends on how you want to handle it.